# MODIS: MYD021KM data set - can't find radiance scales to convert SI to radiances

Tags: fields-attributes, modis

I would like to convert the scaled integers (SI) to radiances for all my SDS MYD021Km thermal emissive bands.

In the MODIS Level 1B Product [user guide](https://mcst.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/mcst.gsfc/files/file_attachments/M1054D_PUG_083112_final.pdf) on page 36 in section 5.5.1 it says:

> The values of radiance_scales and radiance_offsets are computed inside Level 1B and written as attributes to the Science data sets. Thus, radiance may be simply recovered from SI by reading these two attributes and applying Equation 5.8.

where Equation 5.8 states the relation between radiance, radiance_scales and radiance_offsets. However, I can't find those attributes in my hdf file. Even though, I downloaded the whole package without any post-processing choices on LAADS DAAC.

Where can i find them?

Comment: What tools do you have to work with HDF-EOS files?

Comment: HDFView....I figured out this morning that one can right click on the subsetdata and click on "show attributes" :) But your solution below is much better. Thanks a lot! Would you know of any python library that can handle hdf4? My gdal can't read hdf4...only hdf5.

Comment: Unfortunately certain builds of gdal are shipped without the "obsolete" HDF4 support. You might have some luck with the `netCDF4` module that can read HDF4 but does not have support for HDF-EOS geolocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers you are asking for are stored in the HDF-EOS v2 file as attributes. The way to extract attributes depends on the choice of tools available to you.

If you have command-line programs for HDF4, you could use a version of `ncdump` utility built with HDF4 support. It may be called `ncdump` or `hncdump` depending on your distribution.

```
hncdump -h MOD021KM.A2018150.0020.005.2018151073854.hdf | grep -E \
'(band_names|radiance_(scales|offsets)|reflectance_(scales|offsets))'
```

Would output the following list:

```
    EV_1KM_RefSB:band_names = "8,9,10,11,12,13lo,13hi,14lo,14hi,15,16,17,18,19,26" ;
    EV_1KM_RefSB:radiance_scales = 0.013427167f, 0.0084019899f, 0.0054145837f, 0.0036830753f, 0.0034992441f, 0.0011288056f, 0.00084021641f, 0.0015078289f, 0.00083084067f, 0.0010439196f, 0.00093331479f, 0.00810323f, 0.0091102663f, 0.0075753126f, 0.0032291501f ;
    EV_1KM_RefSB:radiance_offsets = 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f ;
    EV_1KM_RefSB:reflectance_scales = 2.4827241e-05f, 1.4246029e-05f, 8.8230718e-06f, 6.3097509e-06f, 5.9693111e-06f, 2.3535526e-06f, 1.7518461e-06f, 3.2272799e-06f, 1.7782888e-06f, 2.6024989e-06f, 3.096286e-06f, 2.7981168e-05f, 3.3658562e-05f, 2.8003564e-05f, 2.856155e-05f ;
    EV_1KM_RefSB:reflectance_offsets = 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f, 316.9722f ;
    EV_1KM_Emissive:band_names = "20,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36" ;
    EV_1KM_Emissive:radiance_scales = 6.2623985e-05f, 0.0031495101f, 6.9215974e-05f, 7.9103978e-05f, 3.1556141e-05f, 5.6398207e-05f, 0.0001175573f, 0.00019244973f, 0.00053248694f, 0.00040632344f, 0.000840022f, 0.00072969758f, 0.00026226387f, 0.00020069582f, 0.00017670827f, 0.00011833857f ;
    EV_1KM_Emissive:radiance_offsets = 2730.5835f, 2730.5835f, 2730.5835f, 2730.5835f, 1077.4448f, 1560.3334f, 2730.5833f, 2317.4883f, 2730.5835f, 1560.3333f, 1577.3397f, 1658.2213f, 2501.2976f, 2501.2976f, 2501.2979f, 2501.2979f ;
    EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB:band_names = "1,2" ;
    EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB:radiance_scales = 0.02789869f, 0.010482604f ;
    EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB:radiance_offsets = -0.f, -0.f ;
    EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB:reflectance_scales = 5.6068438e-05f, 3.4103123e-05f ;
    EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB:reflectance_offsets = -0.f, -0.f ;
    EV_500_Aggr1km_RefSB:band_names = "3,4,5,6,7" ;
    EV_500_Aggr1km_RefSB:radiance_scales = 0.034588818f, 0.025763946f, 0.0062726424f, 0.0027750582f, 0.00086950249f ;
    EV_500_Aggr1km_RefSB:radiance_offsets = -0.f, -0.f, -0.f, -0.f, -0.f ;
    EV_500_Aggr1km_RefSB:reflectance_scales = 5.3474156e-05f, 4.456985e-05f, 4.2685773e-05f, 3.7288173e-05f, 3.1073403e-05f ;
    EV_500_Aggr1km_RefSB:reflectance_offsets = -0.f, -0.f, -0.f, -0.f, -0.f ;
    EV_Band26:radiance_scales = 0.0032291501f ;
    EV_Band26:radiance_offsets = 316.9722f ;
    EV_Band26:reflectance_scales = 2.856155e-05f ;
    EV_Band26:reflectance_offsets = 316.9722f ;
```

So you can get `radiance_scales` and `radiance_offsets` for each MODIS band.

Note that the scales for band 26 are stored twice, first in the array `EV_1KM_RefSB:radiance_scales` and in `EV_Band26:radiance_scales`. The same is true for radiance offsets, reflectance scales and reflectance offsets for Band 26.

Comment: is it really "hncdump" instead of ncdump?

Comment: @Shaun_UZH you are quite right, ncdump comes in different flavors, i.e. Unidata and HDF Group. Some distributions, e.g. SUSE Linux call the HDF Group version `hncdump` to disambiguate.