# Using MODIS metadata in R

Tags: r, modis

I am working with MODIS 1b Data in R, and converted the HDF files into tiffs. They load and plot correctly.

I am now trying to convert the values of corrected_counts_scale and corrected_counts_offset to dn** as described in the User Guide.

This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288850/modis-myd021km-data-set-cant-find-radiance-scales-to-convert-si-to-radiances) describes how to read this information using the CMD point. Is there a way to do this using R?

** edit - to be clear that I am not trying to use the Tiff files directly to access the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this page:

https://hdfeos.org/software/r.php

You need to read your HDF files for the values as tiff will not have this metadata.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have tried this, however  - https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ncdf4_1.15.tar.gz - returns a 404 error so there is no way to download the package with hdf4 functionality included. #

Comment: You should be able to use `install.packages("ncdf4")` to install the package.

Comment: If you add both the `raster` and `ncdf4` packages into the working R environment you can read hdf4 raster files using `raster` or `stack`.